# Swift push notification received but not popped up

Tags: ios, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I've added to my app the remote notification feature, I can receive push notifications, but when I receive it, there is no automatic popup displayed.

here it my AppDelegate code:

```
func application( application: UIApplication,
                  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
    GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
    // Handle the received message
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,userInfo: userInfo)
```

my app is correctly connected to GCM Server, and I receive the following logs while receiving a notification:

```
Notification received: [collapse_key: do_not_collapse, from: 22334444232]
```

on the server side, I'm sending a basic Payload such as:

```
{{"aps":{"alert":"Hello world!","badge":0, "sound": "default"}, "to":"MY_TOKEN_KEY", }
```

any idea why my app is not treating automatically the notification received ?

EDIT1:

I also tried to change the message payload to match Google's GCM tutorial for IOS:

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "Hello world",
"title" : "alert data"
}
```

}

but still just getting didReceiveRemoteNotification function called with the following logs:

```
Notification received : [aps: {
alert =     {
    body = "Hello world";
    title = "alert data";
};
```

}, gcm.message_id: 0:1470516999022408%f1xxxxxx....]

Comment: are you using the app when notification arrived? ios will not pop up the alert if the app is in foreground when receive remote notification. If not, you need to check the GCM notification payload format.

Comment: yes, the app is in foreground. but if I put the app in background, the GCM connection is disabled.....

Comment: no, it will still work, otherwise GCM is useless...I think the socket connection is used for other purpose. You can do a test.

Comment: you were right...it works only in background....not possible to popup a notif when app is in foreground ? may be by using Alert message ?

Comment: you can send local notification when app is in foreground, so that the notification panel will have a record. Or you can just show a UIAlertView to notify the user?

Comment: Yes, I will use UIAlertView... Thks